# I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset

Tags: java, maven, clojure, socketexception

I have my clojure app running on top of Maven, I recently started facing this issue on server startup and while I execute other `lein` commands (clean/deps etc).

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute

INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
```

I've tried,

- updating my Java/Maven versions.
- Double-checked firewall/anti-virus issues. They're all off.
- Since I'm connected to the VPN, checked the configurations and they seem normal.

I'm trying to figure out what's causing this issue.

Comment: There is very little information for us to help you, like what is the Clojure library that you are using (if any - or are you using Java interop ?), and maybe a snippet of code : how do you start your web server ?

Comment: can you confirm that this error happens when you run "lein new hello-test" from outside any existing project?